# Psi 0, 1, or 2 games - are credits from thin air or player's pool?

Tags: android-netrunner

Psychic Field mentions spending credits. Are both players actually spending these credits from their credit pool, or are these imaginary credits?

If a runner has 0 credits, this is basically a guaranteed win?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It is only a guaranteed win if the runner has no way of preventing net damage.

Comment: This card is never a guaranteed win, because it only deals as much damage as the runner has cards in hand. You need to do cards in hand +1 to flatline the runner.

Comment: @shanodin win the psi game. Not the whole game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this card is an example of the Psi game mechanic, and credits are always spent from your credit pool. If aplayer has no credits, then they can only bid 0 during the Psi game (note: this is an excellent way of dealing with Caprice Nisei!).

From the manual (p.7),

> Credit Pool: Each player has a credit pool where he keeps the credit
>   tokens he has available to spend. Spent credits are returned to the
>   token bank.

Comment: It's worth noting that credits can be spent from anywhere, not just the credit pool, as long as they are legal to spend on psi games. For instance Ghost Runner credits can be spent for psi games.